# PhantomJS+Capybara+RSpec get default PhantomJs Example Domain

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, phantomjs

When I set js: true in my test, I get the default website:

"This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this"...

But when I dissable js: true, I get my right webpage. Also, I tryed with js_erros: false but does not work.

`it 'my tests', js: true do
  # ....
end`

Anyone knows something about it? Anything to read? I looked for a while for a solution without results.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your `something_url` to `something_path`.

I was having the same problem and this approach solved it. I hope it helps!